# Delete all hidden files in folder and subfolders

Tags: bash, terminal, solaris

I need to delete all hidden files in the current folder and its sub folders. Is there any way to do it with a single line command without creating a script?

Comment: You mean `find $some_directory '.*' -delete`?

Comment: I normally use `.??*` to avoid that "." or ".." matches. This is especially useful if you're doing a `rm -rf .??*` (which doesn't delete the dot-files from subdirectories).

Comment: Minor quibble: `.??*` would miss "valid" dot files or directories like `.a`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use

```
find "$some_directory" -type f -name '.*' -delete
```

If you want to remove hidden directories as well, you'll need to take a little more care to avoid `.` and `..`, as mentioned by Ronald.

```
find "$some_directory" -name '.*' ! -name '.' ! -name '..' -delete
```

With either command, you should run without the `-delete` primary first, to verify that the list of files/directories that `find` returns includes only files you really want to delete.

For completeness, I should point out that `-delete` is a GNU extension to `find`; the POSIX-compliant command would be

```
find "$some_directory" -type f -name '.*' -exec rm '{}' \;
```

i.e., replace `-delete` with `-exec ... \;`, with `...` replaced with the command line you would use to remove a file, but with the actual file name replaced by `'{}'`.

Comment: The glob pattern `'.[^.]*'` should find hidden files that are not `.` or `..`

Comment: That worked but the -delete flag is not supported by find in my OS. So I used this find "$some_directory" -type f -name '.*' | xargs rm

Answer (score 1):

For my Netgear Stora,  I wanted to remove all the hidden .webview .thumbnails .AppleDouble etc files and folders.
This works from the  /home/yourusername/ folder:

```
find -type f -name '.*' ! -name '.' ! -name '..'  -exec rm -fv '{}' \;
```

and then

```
find -type d -name '.*' ! -name '.' ! -name '..'  -exec rm -frdv '{}' \;
```